# how to check whether a particular value is already present in the oracle db, before adding rows using prepared statements

Tags: java, prepared-statement

```
   INSERT INTO TABLE1 (REPORT_TYPE, CHANNEL,  ACTIVE, CREATION_DATE)
               VALUES(?,?,?,to_date(sysdate,'DD-MM-yyyy');
```

Before adding the above row, I want to check the DB, whether any duplicate data for column `ACTIVE` is present or not.

Comment: For mysql we use insert ignore,check if it supports oracle also or not

Comment: Its not working for oracle